# How to find the usage of method in Java code where the arguments are compound expressions?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search, intellij-idea-2018

Probably a duplicate, but I don't know how to search for it..

I use IntelliJ to find method usages. Now I want to find these usages (method calls) where in the method call itself the argument is an expression.

So not a reference to a string or a string literal as argument, but an expression that evaluates to one string.

To clarify out of these three calls I only want to find the last one:

```
get(myString);
get('blabla');
get('blabla ' + myString);
```

I have been looking at IntelliJ's structural search, but I can't get there (quickly).

Comment: Structural search supports regexp, have you tried that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not yet. If there is no way to distinguish between a string being constructed "at call time" and just a string being send, that is what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I used get($arg$+$arg2$) with the right template to search with 'Search Structurally'.